# "Label" in Assembly language

Tags: assembly, 8051

I have couple of examples which are pretty simple except LABEL concept.
Example 1 adds 25 10 times in itself, whereas example 2 takes complement of Register A 700 times.

```
Example-1:    MOV A,#0
              MOV R2,#10
AGAIN:        ADD A,#25
              DJNZ R2,AGAIN
              MOV R5,A

Example-2:
              MOV A,#55H   
              MOV R3,#10
NEXT:         MOV R2,#70
AGAIN:        CPL A
              DJNZ R2,AGAIN
              DJNZ R3,NEXT
```

I am unable to understand the concept of LABEL. In example-1, when first time program runs, A gets value 25, and then when R2 decrements from 10 to 1, output is 275 instead of 250. But if I assume that LABEL is bypassed unless it is called, then things are ok and I get result 250. But if I assume the same thing (bypassing the LABEL in step by step execution) in Example-2, then LABEL NEXT will be bypassed. And "DJNZ R2,AGAIN" will be executed. As NEXT was bypassed, then how will R2 get the value #70? So my question is about execution of LABEL. Are the LABELS executed or bypassed?

Comment: A "LABEL" is something so that you don't have to manually work out the addresses to jump to. It is *not* an instruction and takes up no space (excepting as the assembler might align code to make it valid).

Comment: A Label is not something you bypass or not - it is just a symbolic name for the address where the following instruction is located. You could add a label in front of each line without impact - unless you actually use it to jump to it or to call it.

Comment: Right. Then In Example-1, When 1st time program runs, Add command adds 25 to A, and when 10 times DJNZ adds 25 in A it should come out to be 275. But in example answer comes out to be 250. How is that?

Comment: It iterates 10 times. The first time `DJNZ` executes, `R2` becomes 9, then 8, then 7, etc., down to 0. So 10 additions of 25 to zero.

Answer (score 1):

> and when 10 times DJNZ adds 25 in A it should come out to be 275

No, 250 is the correct answer. **After** the 10th add instruction, register `R2` still contains `1` - it then gets decremented to 0 and **then** the DJNZ instruction **does not** jump to the label anymore, but skips to the following instruction.

You can regard `DJNZ` as two instructions, similar to

```
DEC  R2
JNZ  AGAIN    ; NOTE: 8051 does not have a Zero flag - would need to
              ; use ACC for that, so treat this as pseudo code!
```

You can use a simulator like http://www.edsim51.com/ to step through the instructions and watch how the registers change for each step. That is very useful for learning how specific instructions behave.

Answer (score 0):

Label is not bypassed. If you take a look at working of a loop then u will see that first DJNZ decrements the value of register then if the result is non zero it executes the label. In 1st example, starting from above:

1) A gets zero, then
2) R2 gets 10, then
3) A gets 25, then
4) DJNZ decrements the value of R2 making it 9 and since the result is non zero, executes AGAIN and it adds 25 in A making it 50 and so on.

When the value of R2 reaches 1, DJNZ decrements it and the result is zero so it won't execute AGAIN. Consequently, DJNZ is executed 9 times hence making result 25*9=225. But as 25 was stored in A before the execution of loop DJNZ, the result is 250.
Hope It helps you.

Comment: please [edit] your answer and fix newlines (you can use <br> tag).